# How to make NestJS global exception filter catch an exception thrown by an interceptor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is it possible to make an interceptor throw an error an make it so it will be caught by the global exceptions filter?

Right now, I'm still very much learning how to use NestJS, and I have a small HTTP application with a Global Exception Filter (just like the one one the docs)... Is it possible to make that filter catch errors thrown by an interceptor? Like... My interceptor catches exceptions and throws back a different exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a new global interceptor and use Rxjs observables to achieve this.

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
export class ErrorInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(_context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        // do stuff
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an exception filter, and append the status and message as a json to the response. something like this :

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class MyExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor() {
    console.log('init');
  }

  catch(exception, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const res = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = res.getResponse();
    response.status(400).json(exception.response);
  }
}
```

then, you call this exception filter on your app.main :

```
import { MyExceptionsFilter } from '.';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(SOME-MODULE);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new MyExceptionsFilter());
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

in main.ts define http exception filter globally

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './filters/http.exception.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

in HttpExceptionFilter.ts

```
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  ExceptionFilter,
  HttpException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const res: any = exception.getResponse();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      isSuccess: 'false',
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
      error: res,
    });
  }
}
```